# Audio conversion of CAF file

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, sox

I am recording audio on the iPhone to a CAF file with kAudioFormatiLBC, the recording works fine.

I want to be able to take a sample and also get it to convert to other formats after I have uploaded it to by ruby on rails webservice.

I am trying to use sox but get:

`` sox in.caf out.mp3


sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `in.caf': Supported file format but unsupported encoding. ``

Similar with ffmpeg I get:

`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'in.caf'`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've found ffmpeg will translate caf files with a data format of aac.  I'm capturing voice on the iPhone in AAC format at 22050Hz, 1 channel.  Server side I can translate it to .wav format with ffmpeg and then to .mp3 with sox.

The following shows the configuration for ffmpeg running under FreeBSD.

```
%ffmpeg -i test_aac_22050_1.caf test_pcm_22050_1.wav
FFmpeg version 0.6.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  7 2011 16:16:19 with gcc 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man --enable-shared --enable-    gpl --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-memalign-hack --cc=cc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include/vorbis -I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --extra-libs=-pthread --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-sse --disable-mmx --disable-indev=alsa --disable-outdev=alsa --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --disable-libgsm --disable-libmp3lame --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --disable-ffplay --disable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, caf, from 'test_aac_22050_1.caf':
  Duration: 00:00:09.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 44 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: aac, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 30 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'test_pcm_22050_1.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 352 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
size=     426kB time=9.89 bitrate= 352.8kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:426kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.010087%
```

And confirming the output:

```
%file test_pcm_22050_1.wav 
test_pcm_22050_1.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 22050 Hz
```

Answer (score 3):

SOX has an optional dependency on libsndfile for CoreAudio file processing.

If you use brew(1) run  `brew install libsndfile` prior to brewing sox. You will need to rebuild the sox after you install libsndfile.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running OSX, you should be able to use `afconvert`. Alternatively, use a different codec.

The Wikipedia article on [iLBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILBC) has a few links which might be useful. The top of http://ilbcfreeware.org/software.html links to the RFC and an awk script for extracting the reference source code.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me

```
brew install sox --with-libsndfile
```

if you want to encode mp3 you may also need

```
--with-lame
```